# How to updateOwnPost on function in yii2-admin

Tags: yii2, rbac

I am using yii2-admin. All roles and permissions are added in browser.(/localhost/yiiproject/site/admin/)
Now my problem is I don't how to add `updateOwnPost`. I already read [this](http://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md).
I don't have RbacController.

This is my code.

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

// add the rule
$rule = new \app\rbac\AuthorRule;
$auth->add($rule);

// add the "updateOwnPost" permission and associate the rule with it.
$updateOwnPost = $auth->createPermission('updateOwnPost');
$updateOwnPost->description = 'Update own post';
$updateOwnPost->ruleName = $rule->name;
$auth->add($updateOwnPost);

// "updateOwnPost" will be used from "updatePost"
$auth->addChild($updateOwnPost, $updatePost);

// allow "author" to update their own posts
$auth->addChild($author, $updateOwnPost);
```

Is there an example for updateOwnPost?